# "Clearsigned file isn't valid" error when updating

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, repository

Any time I try to update my system (running Ubuntu 20.04), I receive an error:

```
Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT'
```

This is the full output of what I see when I run `sudo apt update` in the Terminal:

```
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:2 https://repo.protonvpn.com/debian stable InRelease                       
Get:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [638 kB]
Err:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Reading package lists... Done                                                  
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is not signed.
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using a network that requires a proxy connection?

Comment: I use proxy connection sometimes but the network itself does not require proxy.

Comment: If you are updating without using the proxy, does the `update` work without error? If not, has update *ever* worked since adding `ro-mirrors.evowise.com`? Reason I ask is because some proxies will interfere with apt and this requires some settings to be changed 

Comment: yes. update worked since i added ro-mirrors.evowise.com. but recently its showing this kind of error. even though if try to switch the download server, when it comes to refreshing software cache part similar type of errors pop up.